# Changing classes/id's in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently changing a parent theme in wordpress by creating a child theme and I am just checking if this is considered bad form and if it will have any repercussions if/when the theme is updated.

e.g. The parent theme's `header.php` has an id called `#menu`. This has a lot of styles in the parent's `style.css` file. To avoid having to alter everything to do with the `#menu` I changed the id to `#menu-child` in the child theme's `header.php` file and added my own styles, this has made it a lot quicker but I'm unsure if it will screw the styles/theme up if/when it is updated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Your child theme template overwrites the main theme template and still does that after an update. So your changes will stay in place. But if the parent theme uses the `#menu` for stuff (styling, js...) these changes and current adjustments will not have any effect in your child theme anymore. So if you want your own changes and all functionalities and styling of the parent theme you should not remove the id, but add your own class.
Of cause theme developers can sometimes mess up the structure or make changes themselves which require you to alter your child theme templates as well (like changing the whole structure).

Comment: Thanks! How would you recommend leaving the #menu id and adding a class though? Wouldn't the id still have some styling?

Comment: Do you not want to keep the styling of the parent theme? Its really tricky if you do not want to keep parent theme styling and these are done via id's, But if you do not want to keep any of the stylings maybe you want your own theme after all? Usually wihtin a child theme you would overwrite stylings and append stylings via own classes like: #main { color: #myowncolor } #main.my-child-theme { //your stylings } (this could also be directly on the id, but it makes it easer to seperate the overwrites from your own stylings)

Comment: I want to keep the styling apart from a few things to do with the menu - at the moment the theme is a hamburger style menu. I'm having it so the menu items are showing without the hamburger menu.

Comment: if its only about the visibility it might be easier to overwrite it on the current id menu: #menu {display:block} -> but if the burger menu is triggered and initialized via js, probably your first approach with a custom id is the better solution to get rid of any js functionality as well (depending on how the js is bound to the element, its could also be a data tag or a class)

Comment: Thanks, I'll show you an example of what I mean... so this is a part of the parent style.css menu #menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  top: 60px;
}#menu > ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after,
#menu > ul ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  height: auto;
  content: '\f107';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  line-height: 12px;
}
but I don't want some of those to be applicable. Like how do I get rid of all of the 2nd styling?

Comment: Well you have to overwrite all properties one by one. I cannot decide for you whats the better approch: style it all yourself or orwrite all these properties. You have to guess which one is simpler and that depens on how man of the styles you want to keep. The advantage of keeping the class and overwriting is that you stick with the original theme structure. The disadvantage ist the code overhead and if you do not want the same look at all, you will also not want updates to mess with your custom element... so its up to you :-)